# is there a way to make two states update in two sperate renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

i am trying to make an e-commerce cart using react.js and i faced a problem as following.

```
const [item, setItems] = useState([]);
const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);


....

const CartItem = (props) => {
        const { img, title, id, price, obj, product1 } = props;
        // obj is counter for the initial number of the item that is 
        // being passed from the parent component
        const [counter, setCounter] = useState(obj);

        

        

        function increment() {
            setPrice(price);
            setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
            let arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
            arr.push(product1);
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(arr));
        }

        function decrement() {
            let arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
            let index = -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i].title === title) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (index != -1) {
                arr.splice(index, 1);
                setCounter((prev) => prev - 1);
                setPrice((pre) => pre - price);

                localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(arr));
            }
        }

        return (
            <div className="p">
                <div className="cartr">
                    {" "}
                    <Link to={`/e-commerce-project/products/${id}`}>
                        <img src={img} alt="" className=" cart-img" />
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="titlee"> {title}</div>
                <div className="cart-price">price : ${price}</div>
                <button className="add-button" onClick={increment}>
                    +
                </button>
                <div className="quantity"> quantity : {counter}</div>
                <button className="remove-button" onClick={decrement}>
                    -
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

this code block is used for increasing and decreasing the item added to the cart and then changing the price, but when i use it only
updates the price the item number is also updating but it shows after refreshing.

is there is a good way to solve this problem?

i am still not familiar with react hooks so excuse me for the mistakes.

i've tried searching for a solution and i found out that the two states are being updated in one render.

Comment: This piece of code only shows how you are updating it. Can you also show how you are displaying the count and price. From the question  and the shared code, I assume you are using localstorage for that as well. Can you confirm that point ?

Comment: sure, i will add the whole component

Comment: i am using the local storage to pass from the item page to the cart, by adding the item to the localstorage and then getting it in the cart page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could understand from your question, your `item` state which is present in the parent is not updating correctly and you are using `localstorage` for updating `item` from the child component (Cart).

If the above is really what you meant, then instead of using `localstorage` to update `item` inside Cart component, you can pass the `setItems` function from the parent component to the Cart component via props. Now, inside your `increment` and `decrement` functions, you can directly use this `setItems` function and this will directly affect your parent component and trigger a re-render for your parent.

Also, if you are using the `localstorage` value for some other purpose, you can sync the changes from the `item` state variable to its `localstorage` counter part by using an effect which will run whenever the value of `item` state changes (by using [item] as the dependency array)

Comment: i am already using useEffect to update the localstorage if any item is added